# use Regex to get a string from a file

Tags: ansible, regex, ansible-playbook

I'm a beginner with regex Basically what I have on the line of my file is:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.xxx.dtes.sp.file = '/home/share/9WR/config/application1-t-sp.html'   // for unix file based
```

And I want to get the path and the file that is referencing:

```
/home/share/9WR/config/application1-t-sp.html
```

Is there a way to do this with regex?

Comment: Is filename fixed ?  or is it any .html file to identify  ?   if so a simple regexp can do the spot.

Comment: it could be any html file to identify. I found this, but not sure if is the best solution: 
```
(?:^|\s)'([^']*?)'(?:\s|$)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `regex` the [`ini`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/ini.html#ini-read-data-from-a-ini-file) plugin might be a better choice. For example, given the file

```
shell> cat test.ini 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.xxx.dtes.sp.file = '/home/share/9WR/config/application1-t-sp.html'   // for unix file based
```

the task

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('ini',
                        'grails.plugin.springsecurity.xxx.dtes.sp.file
                        type=properties
                        file=test.ini') }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": "'/home/share/9WR/config/application1-t-sp.html'   // for unix file based"
```

---

Notes

- `lookup` works with local files only